# How to manipulate an excel workbook with Excel.Workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel

So, I can't find any methods with file opening in `Excel.Workbook` or `Excel.Application`, and I am wondering why.

I have path to an Excel file, and I would like to manipulate it. I understand I have to use `Excel.Application`, `Excel.Workbook`, and `Excel.Worksheet`. The file to the Excel file is `ExcelFilePath`, what should I do to make it possible?

Comment: what manipulation in workbook ? like add sheet or remove sheet ?

Comment: cell level manipulation, like this: http://superuser.com/questions/540944/how-to-achieve-something-like-this-in-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to add the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to your project in order to use the Excel API, then fill the variables:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
xlWS = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(sheetNameOrIndex), Excel.Worksheet)
```

And then you only need to use the methods they have. For example:

```
Dim sVar as String = xlWS.Range("C5").Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: from my project

```
Dim xapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook = xapp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Activate()

    'Fill header of the sheet----------------------------------
    For i As Integer = 1 To dgvcustomer.Columns.Count
        ws.Cells(1, i) = dgvcustomer.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
    Next
    'End header------------------------------------------------

    Dim Dgrow, Dgcell, Dgcol As Integer
    Dgrow = 1
    Dgcell = 1

    'Fill Sheet ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    While (Dgrow <= dgvcustomer.Rows.Count)
        Dgcol = 1
        While (Dgcol <= ws.UsedRange.Columns().Count)
            ws.Cells(Dgrow + 1, Dgcol).value = dgvcustomer.Rows(Dgrow - 1).Cells(ws.Cells(1, Dgcol).value).Value
            Dgcol += 1
        End While
        Dgrow += 1
    End While

    'End fill sheet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    wb.SaveAs(dlgSaveFile.FileName)
    wb.Close()
    xapp.Quit()
```

Comment: Alter it according to your need . for any clarification you can comment.

Comment: Fixed . you can check again.

Comment: oh releases the shift key while selecting. :)