# Open Excel File on a specific worksheet through Process.Start() in VB.NET (External Open)

Tags: vb.net, excel

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFQD.png)
I have a database with excel file names stored together with specific worksheet name for each. What I exactly need is to simply open (external) the excel file with the focus to the specific worksheet name.

I simply tried something like following. But it just opens the excel file with the focus on the default worksheet, not the worksheet I want.

Process.Start("X:\myexcelpath\myexcelworkbook.xlsx", "myworksheet")

So please let me know how I can do this stuff in vb.net

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this through a command line. What I would suggest is that you use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

[How to manipulate an excel workbook with Excel.Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497641/how-to-manipulate-an-excel-workbook-with-excel-workbook)

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
xlWS = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(sheetNameOrIndex), Excel.Worksheet)
xlApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: Thanks, But, xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass gives me an error. I'm using Office 2007.

Comment: Oh, I copied that from the other link. ApplicationClass was wrong. I will edit it.

Comment: But again I get an error saying workbook object does not contain a visible property. Please help me. Check for the link in my question post for the error.

Comment: Sorry again, that should have been on the xlApp. Point is, you should so some research on interop so you can see how to work with the excel files in this way. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, it worked me perfectly well. Thanks once again.